# Questions about array and pointer from a beginner

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am new to C++ and to programming in general. I got confused when I learnt the concepts of pointer and array.
Takes `int*p = arr; int arr[]={5,1};` as an example. I learnt that `arr` is also a pointer.

```
                                p(a pointer)                          arr[0]
the thing it stores:    [first element address: 601]                   [5]
its memory         :                501                                601
address(just make 
some fake address)

However,                                 arr(the pointer)
                                  [first element address: 601]
                                               601
```

Normally, a pointer should have a different address from the array. However, the `arr`, as the pointer to the first element, has the same address as the first element. So I feel confused. And I wonder whether it is because the memory box of `arr[0]` is split into two parts: one part for `arr[0]`, and one part for the pointer `arr`, so that they have the same address in memory.

Comment: Use `std::array` and `std::vector`. Mostly forget that C-style arrays exist.

Answer (score 1):

> I learnt that `arr` is also a pointer.

Then you were taught something wrong, which is probably the reason for your confusion.

If you have `int arr[] = {5, 1};` then `arr` is an array, not a pointer. An array can implicitly be converted to a pointer to its first element. But the array itself is still an array. For example, make an `int arr[512];` and check what `sizeof(arr)` is going to be. If `arr` were a pointer, then that should be the same as `sizeof(int*)`. But it isn't because arrays *are not* pointers. They are arrays…

If you write

```cpp
int arr[] = {5, 1, 3};
int* p = arr;
```

what you end up with is something like this:

```
  arr
       +---+---+---+
0xA0:  | 5 | 1 | 3 |
       +---+---+---+

  p
       +-------+
0xB0:  |  0xA0 |
       +-------+
```

Somewhere in memory, let's say at address 0xA0, there will be an object that is an array of three `int`. The identifier `arr` is just a name that denotes this array object in you code. The array object contains three `int` objects placed one after the other. The individual `int`s (elements of the array) are subobjects of the complete array object. Note that the address of the complete array object is the same as the address of the subobject that is the first array element. Nevertheless, there is a difference between the array object `arr`, which is of type `int[3]` and encompasses the whole array, and the first element, which is of type `int`.

Also in memory, let's say at address 0xB0, there will be another object of type `int*`. The identifier `p` is just a name that denotes this pointer object in your code. `p` is a completely separate object from `arr`. It exists at a completely different address. `p` was initialized to point to the result of the expression `arr`. The expression `arr` denotes our array. Pointers and arrays are completely different things. In what way does it make sense to assign an array to a pointer!? What is going on?

To understand why `int* p = arr;` works and what it does, let's back up a little and think about how we would actually access an element of `arr`. If we know the address at which array elements start, we can simply compute the address of any element by just adding the element size times the element index. This is precisely how pointer arithmetic works in C++ (which is not a coincidence): given a pointer `p` to the first element of an array, we can get a pointer to the `i`-th element by just adding them together: `p + i`. In fact, the subscripting operator `[]` for element access such as `p[i]` is literally [defined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.sub#1) as just shorthand notation for `*(p + i)`.

Thus, while arrays and pointers are completely different things, arrays only really become useful once pointers enter the picture. Using an array generally requires accessing its elements. Accessing the elements of an array generally requires pointers. Since you generally need a pointer to the first element to really use an array for anything, arrays can implicitly be converted to a pointer to their first element in C and C++.

When you write `p = arr` what you're really writing is `p = &arr[0]`. Because, while you cannot assign an array to a pointer, an array of `int` can implicitly be converted to an `int*` that points to the first element of the array. And that `int*` *can* be assigned to a pointer. And that's why `p` in our example above will contain the address of the first element of the array (which happens to be the same as the address of the array).

However, since arrays are arrays, not pointers (they just *can* be *converted* to a pointer to the first element *if necessary*), taking the address of an array like `&arr` will result in a pointer to the array object itself (which, as we have seen, has the same address as the first element). The type of `&arr` will be `int(*)[3]` (pointer to array of three `int`). Unlike `&p`, which will actually be a pointer to a pointer to `int`…

Note: When you write `arr[2]`, what you're really writing is `*((&arr[0]) + 2)` because the `[]` operator works on pointers. And arrays are not pointers but can implicitly be converted into a pointer to their first element…

Comment: the array in the lower "graphic" should contain {1,2,3} or the example code should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for pointing that out. fixed. I actually wanted to avoid using 1, 2, 3 to avoid confusion of element value with the element number, so I resolved it the other way around…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Thanks for answering my question. But I still feel confused about it. If the array "can implicitly be converted into a pointer to their first element" if necessary. Then, logically extra memory should be required. Just like our human, when we need to remember that something is a "tree", memory is needed. If necessary, when we further need to remember the type of that "tree" or what can we do with it, extra memory is needed. Then, how come "arr"(not only representing int[3] but also int* if necessary) have the same memory size(through using sizeof) as 3 integers?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that pointers are not a beginner topic in C++, they are mostly just a carry over from C. If you can, you should avoid them and use the [STL Containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

---

In your code sample, the type of `arr` is `int[2]`. You should think of that in memory as looking something like this:

```
arr --+
      |
      v
    +---+---+
    | 5 | 1 |
    +---+---+
```

The value contained in `arr` is the location of the first element (the `5`). `arr` is essentially a pointer to that `5`. The only difference being that the type (`int[2]`) has also remembered how many elements there are.

The assignment statement `p = arr` works because `p`'s type is `int*` which `int[]` can decay to.

Comment: Be very careful saying stuff like *arr is essentially a pointer to that 5* because it is not even though it can be used in much the same way. It is an identifier that represents the whole of the array the same as with `MyStruct mystruct; `mystruct` is more than a pointer to the first member of `MyStruct`. You appear to know this in the next paragraph, but the graphic and the following paragraph are misleading.

Comment: As I said, they aren't a beginner topic. An `int[2]` is an `int*` with more type information; but, that's technically a compiler detail rather than part of the language and shouldn't be in a beginner course or book.